# I don't understand this loop code in Grok

Tags: python, loops

I'm a beginner to Python and learning loops, I can't wrap my head around what this code does

```
output = ''
for i in "Hello":
    output += i
print(output)
print('Next line')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The loop iterates on the given string `"Hello"` and than adds every letter `(i)` to the variable `output`. Try to add `print(i)` to the loop, it will help you understand better.